# KDE Neon GUI won't start after login

Tags: kde, login, plasma, startx, kde-neon

I installed some updates and it needed a reboot which I did. After that I tried to login, but pressing enter after entering the password or clicking the login button with the cursor didn't do anything (so there is no visible reaction of the system after pressing enter). Other buttons like shutdown worked. I tried rebooting but it didn't help. I open the console and I was able to login, but entering `startx` just produced a black screen.

Details about my system:

- KDE neon User Edition 5.16 (64 bit)
- Processor: Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
- GNOME: 3.28.2

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: the XServer had created some lock files that were not deleted. I solved the problem by deleting `home/'user'/.Xauthority-c` and `home/'user'/.Xauthority.l`